# Gettting the primary key which is autoincrement before saving changes in linqtosql

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I am currently using a `Dbsetlist.Count()` to get the primary key of an Autoincremented table where an Row will be saved before any actual saving is performed.. But I feel this approach is not correct but cannot figure out any other alternative purely using Linq can someone suggest how to do this in Linq only?

```
db.Invoicesets.Add(invoice); //Invoicesets is Invoice table as list for Linq
order.invno = db.Invoicesets.Count(); // Invno is needed as a foreign for Order table
db.Ordersets.Add(order); //
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Why do you need the primary key before saving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean, say, you want to add entity `A` first so you can use the identity column of `A,` `A.ID` as the FK to entity `B`? If yes, you can use [InsertOnSubmit()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763516.aspx):

```
db.Invoicesets.InsertOnSubmit(invoice);
order.invo = invoice;
db.orders.InsertOnSubmit(order);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to be very careful here. What happens if two threads, at the same time, execute:

```
order.invno = db.Invoicesets.Count();
```

You will have two orders with the same invno field, which is probably something you don't want.

I'm guessing that field should have a unique constraint on it, and is perhaps your primary key? I don't think there is any LINQ only way to do this, I think you need to make invno an Identity column, that way you'll be assured that it will increment and remain unique.

**EDIT**

As an aside, you could also generate a GUID for invno in your application code, but obviously you'll have to change the datatype of the invno field in your db.

Comment: Thanks Chris. But will it be a problem if I `db.SaveChanges()` and get then `invoice.Id`?

Comment: So Invoice.Id is your primary key? Is it an identity column? I am a little confused about what you're trying to do. If you are incrementing an Identity column (if you're using SQL Server), you can use SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() to determine the last identity value inserted in the table in your session. You'll have to work with the db on this.